# Can a term be its own coefficent in algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a question in my math book; it asks me to find the coefficient of $b$ in the expression $3a+b+2c$. I thought, well, there is no coefficient of $b$, so I went on and then I wanted to go see if I was right at the back off the book and it says that $b$ counts as its own coefficient and I don't get it. Help explain it to me please; I`m so stuck. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the coefficient be 1?

Comment: why I need to no why its 1

Answer (score 4):

It is an important basic fact that no matter what number $b$ is, $1b = b$.

So when you're asking about the "coefficient" of a certain term in a polynomial, and there isn't one written out explicitly, it makes the most sense to say that it is $1$.

If your book says otherwise, I recommend that you get a different book. Please let us know what book it is, so we can be sure not to use it.

Comment: thank! you first every one who commented its not that the book is wrong it just does not go into detail.